# Error 409 Conflict when deploy with Jenkins in Anypoint Platform (CloudHub)

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment, mulesoft, cloudhub

We deployed without problems in Anypoint Platform (CloudHub) using Jenkins. Now having problems.

The log shows that the answer is 409 Conflict when trying to deploy.
This is the exact error:

```
[ERROR] Failed: 409 Conflict: {"status": 409, "message": "Application not updated"}
[ERROR] Failed to deploy myApplicationName: Failed to deploy application myApplicationName
```

Also:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:2.2.1:deploy (deploy) 
on project myApplicationName: 
Failed to deploy [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/.jenkins/workspace/JDE System API/myApplicationName/
target/myApplicationName-1.0.6.zip] -> [Help 1]
```

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal

As possible solutions we find changing the Maven to 2.2.1 but it is the one we are using.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to Mule Maven Plugin latest release for Mule 3.x ([2.3.3](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-maven-plugin/mule-maven-plugin-2.3.3-release-notes)) should resolve that issue. Note that migrating from earlier than 2.3.0 requires adapting the plugin configuration. The link above points to documentation.

Comment: I am getting that error even using the 3.5.3 plugin.

Comment: Mule Maven plugin releases < 3.0.0 are for Mule 3. Releases >= 3.0.0 are for Mule 4 applications, which are not compatible with Mule 3. Your question implies that you were using Mule 3. I don't understand how did you update to Mule Maven plugin 3.5.3 without migrating the application to Mule 4.

Comment: @Luciano I just noticed that you are not the original poster. You probably have a different issue. Please open a new question with all the details.

Comment: In my case I just gave CloudHub some time (minutes) and launched the deploy again, and it worked. Btw, I'm not using Jenkins bug Gitlab pipelines. Thank you anyway for answering, our messages might still help someone in the future.